# Make the thread wait() until UI input event

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am working with an Android development environment.

I have thread running in the background with a complicated structure of for loops. For each run of the "for loop" I want to listen to some UI input, collect the result and continue the "for loop". To abstract the question making it more brief please look at the following code：

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        mLeftText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.leftText);            
        mVerboseText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.verbose);

        LoopTask taskA = new LoopTask();
        Thread a = new Thread(taskA);
        a.start();


    }       

    class LoopTask implements Runnable {


        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (mSync) {

                mLeftText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        doSomething();
                        mSync.notify();
                    }
                });    

                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    try {                           
                        mSync.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I know that I must have done something wrong, because it is throwing me exception: **"java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before notify()"**

I am trying this complicated structure only because my loop structure is quite complicated and I am not able to using some data structure to record the progress of the loop and continue onClickEvent is triggered.

Please let me know how to fix it and if any alternative solutions are welcomed.

Thanks

Comment: I want to keep the forloop structure in the main background thread. Only awake the thread once the user input is done. Just think about how the readline() is working for the normal console programme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you must remember these two things:

**you MUST NOT make your UI thread wait,**

**you CAN NOT Manipulate UI from Outside of your UI thread**

for those who think:

> You are contradicting yourself... "Do not make the UI-Thread wait" and
>   then you code a synchronized block into the UI-Thread ? It should be
>   ok, if these two are the only accesses to it, but it is a possible
>   hazard -> app not responding

I do not make my UI wait, look at my code carefully although note when a thread call `wait` it release the lock(mSync). and also in my opinion there is no chance of `APR`, you can read my comment below other answer.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }
    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        public class MonitorObject{
        }
        final MonitorObject mSync = new MonitorObject();
        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);

            TextView txt = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
            txt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    synchronized (mSync) {
                         mSync.notify();

                }
            });    

            LoopTask taskA = new LoopTask();
            Thread a = new Thread(taskA);
            a.start();
            return rootView;
        }

        class LoopTask implements Runnable {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    synchronized (mSync) {
                        try {
                            mSync.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    final int runNumber = i; 
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "inside the thread1 " + runNumber , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

and xml files:

activity_main.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.thread_notify_wait.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

fragment_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="16dip"
    android:paddingLeft="16dip"
    android:paddingRight="16dip"
    android:paddingTop="16dip"
    tools:context="com.example.thread_notify_wait.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="mmlooloo: Hello TypingPanda" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: the target I want to achieve is that I want to have a Thread, ThreadA, which is different from UIThread (because I want to hold the forloop in this ThreadA but I know I should not hold UIThread). For each run inside the forloop in the ThreadA I am expecting a UI input from UIThread and once I got the input I want to continue with the loop for the next run. How can I achieve that?

Comment: mmlooloo, sorry probably I haven't explained myself clearly. I want to keep the forloop structure in the main background thread. Only awake the thread once the user input is done. Just think about how the readline() is working for the normal console programme. Thanks

Comment: look at new solution !!

Comment: You are contradicting yourself... "Do not make the UI-Thread wait" and then you code a synchronized block into the UI-Thread ? It should be ok, if these two are the only accesses to it, but it is a possible hazard -> app not responding.

Comment: @Falco you misunderstand man, i do not wait on UI thread pay attention and you will get the result.

Comment: @Falco for updating your knowledge `Once a thread calls wait() it releases the lock it holds on the monitor object. This allows other threads to call wait() or notify() too, since these methods must be called from inside a synchronized block.` http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/thread-signaling.html

Comment: @mmlooloo 1. OnClick is called on the UI-Thread 2. A syncrhonized Block will always wait and halt execution until the referenced object is available. - If you have a synchronized block on the UI-Thread you have a possible hanging-point, if the same object is used by another thread: Scenario - the Background-Thread enters synchronized, gets suspended by the system because resources run low, the UI-Thread enters OnClick and needs to wait for the background-thread to call wait(), if the background-thread is suspended it can wait long -> App not responding!

Comment: @mmlooloo Entering the synchronized block and calling wait() are two separate actions, if the Thread gets suspended in between, it will hold a lock on the object and block the UI-Thread!

Comment: @Falco 1.`if the UI thread is blocked for more than a few seconds (about 5 seconds currently) the user is presented with the infamous "application not responding" (ANR) dialog.` obviously suspension time is not that. 2. can you give a reference that android kills a thread inside process to reclaim memory. i said thread not a service and so on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61551/discussion-between-falco-and-mmlooloo).

Comment: You can write out a bounty on this question and give it to my answer after the waiting time!

Comment: I find my request self-contradicting. And I am looking for some other solutions to the issue. Thanks for you answer.

Comment: @TypingPanda no my code is correct and dose not make your UI thread wait, look at it, it never blocks UI thread.

Comment: double checked, mmlooloo's code is working fine for me~ Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that the method *onClickListener()* is executed by an external thread, which is different from the thread you created (the one actually holding the lock on mSync). So when it gets to *notify()* it complains about not having the lock. You can accomplish the same with a Semaphore initialized with 0. Your code would look something like this:

```
class LoopTask implements Runnable {

    private Semaphore s = new Semaphore(0);
    @Override
     public void run() {

            mLeftText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    doSomething();
                    s.release();
                }
            });    

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                try {                           
                    s.acquire();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    }
}
```

There is a difference among semaphores and notify/wait, though: when you call *notify()* and there is no thread blocked on *wait()*, that call is lost, it doesn't accumulate so the next call to *wait()* doesn't block. With semaphores, if you call *release()* once, then the next call to *acquire()* will not block.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Eduardo, thanks for you answer. I tired your method. It only works if I don't manipulate the UI inside the LoopTask. While I want the update UI to happen either inside the loopTask or by the onClickListener, is that possible?

Comment: @TypingPanda I edited in the suggestion from mmlooloo, all UI-Stuff needs to happen in the UI-Thread, so you have to wrap it in "runOnUiThread"

Answer (score -1):

The best solution is a Semaphore and runOnUiThread for any changes on the UI!

An important addition: If you want to use synchronize - be aware that a call to synchronize may be blocking. Even if the Background Thread will just call `synchronized (s) { s.wait(); }` The Thread may be paused/suspended for various reasons after the lock is aquired, but before it is released again with wait(). In this case the UI-Thread will block and your UI will hang until the background-thread is activated again and gets execution time to release the lock. Since the Dalvik-VM on Android implements Java-Threads as native linux-threads, they have different priorities and fight for the same system resources. Since there may be many threads with a higher priority than the background thread (concurrent GC, ui-threads, system-threads) on a heavy loaded system the background thread may be very slow, because it gets very few ressources, while the UI-Thread will get a high priority and is tweaked to run very often. In the worst case scenario you UI-Thread will hang waiting for the background thread to release the lock more than 5 seconds and trigger 'application not responding'

So the way to go about this is either: call `synchronized(s){s.notify()}` on a separate thread or use a semaphore which will handle these issues natively with a two-step non-blocking synchronisation on Semaphore.release()

```
private Semaphore s = new Semaphore(0);

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    final Thread a = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            loopTask();
        }
    }.start();

    TextView txt = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
    txt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // s.release() will not Block the UI-Thread
            // even if Background-Task is suspended
            // Because of Semaphore two-step implementation
            s.release();
        }
    });    

    return rootView;
}

public void loopTask() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        try {
            s.acquire();

            final int runNumber = i;
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // Any UI Action happens here!!!
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Running Loop " + runNumber , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain me why https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/f05c07d3528765076adc16337a1f68f1700955dc/v4/java/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.java#L100 is used, as you said it may create `ANR`

Comment: and also https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/f05c07d3528765076adc16337a1f68f1700955dc/v4/java/android/support/v4/util/LruCache.java#L333

Comment: if so the other thread can take a lock and block indefinitely but android source code dose not think so!!

Comment: as i search i am finding lots of example this is a volley request queue http://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue.html#singleton

Comment: please tell why all of them use `synchronize block` on the UI thread

Comment: all android source codes and libraries use `synchronize block` on the UI thread and none of them thought about thread being `blocked indefinitely`

Comment: Using synchronized blocks for singletons in this way is pretty bad and no recommended practice, because of the performance implications. But a big part of Android code isn't very optimized in this way - if you search on SO about singleton-patterns this use is discouraged. And synchronized is an acceptable risk if you have Threads of similar priority and runtime requirements, otherwise it can lead to lagging UI. It also depends on how often a method is called, because if the chance of locking up is about 1 in a billion it's likely accepted if the code is called once per app launch.

Comment: But in a highly concurrent part of the program and under unfavorable system conditions I stand by my answer that calling synchronized methods from the UI Thread which can be locked by a low-priority thread is a risk.

Comment: i think your knowledge is much much further from android developer engineer, you just do not want to accept your mistake. obviously android dev team know all of these issues.